# TwoWay Binding of a ComboBox to a static property in .NET 4.5

Tags: xaml, data-binding, combobox, .net-4.5, two-way-binding

Well, i just posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468502/twoway-binding-of-a-combobox-to-a-static-property) question, but i figured that i am not doing anything wrong. My code (and the code of all of the answers) is correct, but my dev-maschine runs with .NET4.5 which apparently has a problem with the binding of the combobox...

So here a new version of the question: **How to two-way bind a combobox's SelectedItem to a static Property in .NET4.5?**

The following code snippets work in .net4 but not in .NET4.5. In 4.5 it is just that the selected value is not propagated back into my static property.

My ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public static List<String> MyElements { get; set; }
    public static string SelectedElement { get; set; }

    static MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        MyElements = new List<string>() {"a", "b", "c"};
        SelectedElement = "a";
    }
}
```

And my XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <me:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="model"/>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static me:MainWindowViewModel.MyElements}, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource model}, Path=SelectedElement}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Does anybody have an idea how to achieve this two-way binding of a ComboBox's SelectedItem to a static Property in .NET4.5?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [my report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774112/net-4-5-compatibility-wpf-listbox-datagrid-binding-on-selecteditem-fails) on Microsoft Connect. Every `Selector` control is infected by this issue.

Finally, a few weeks ago Microsoft released an appropriate patch which has already been distributed through Windows Update. [see Knowledge Base KB2805222](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2805222/en-us) (WPF - Issue 7)

> WPF - Issue 7:
>   *Assume that you change a selector property (such as, the SelectedItem property) or ComboBox.Text property by using a binding path that contains a static property. In this situation, the binding does not react to the changes. Specifically, the new value is not written to the data item.*